# Socket.io messaging app not sending messages with express server

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io, messaging

I'm building a messaging feature with socket.io and a React frontend. With a socket.io only server it is working as expected, with the following code:

**Socket.io server only**

```
const io = require("socket.io")(5000, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    const id = socket.handshake.query.id;
    socket.join(id);

    socket.on("send-message", ({ recipients, text }) => {
        recipients.forEach((recipient) => {
            const newRecipients = recipients.filter((r) => r !== recipient);
            newRecipients.push(id);
            socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit("receive-message", {
                recipients: newRecipients,
                sender: id,
                text,
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to integrate with express. The server is starting with the code below but messaging is no longer working:

**Express server**

```
const express = require("express");
const socketIo = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

const http = app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:${PORT}`)
);

const io = socketIo(http, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST", "send-message", "receive-message"],
    },
});

io.once("connection", (socket) => {
    const id = socket.handshake.query.id;
    socket.join(id);

    socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
    });

    socket.on("send-message", ({ recipients, text }) => {
        recipients.forEach((recipient) => {
            const newRecipients = recipients.filter((r) => r !== recipient);
            newRecipients.push(id);
            socket.broadcast.to(recipient).emit("receive-message", {
                recipients: newRecipients,
                sender: id,
                text,
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Running it locally for both instances in Chrome with a window and another incognito window open on localhost:3000

Comment: Please add some more explanations to your final goal, and what is the actual error or problem.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-socket-instance/) `on('connection')` event on client side not work. Change it to `on('connect')`;

```
// server-side
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
});

// client-side
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id); // x8WIv7-mJelg7on_ALbx
});
```